# Javascript, preserving this reference when passing function argument

Tags: javascript, object, callback

I'm inside a function of an object and I need to call an external function and pass a reference to a function as argument. This last function argument uses the keyword `this` several times so I need to be scoped into my object. I solved this by doing:

```
   MyObj.prototype.internalFunc= function(data){
       this.doSomethingWithReturnedData(data);
   };

   MyObj.prototype.doSomething= function(){
       var $this = this;
       externalFunction(this.someVar, function(data){ $this.internalFunc(data); });
   };

   var objInst = new MyObj();
   objInst.doSomething();
```

I want to know if there is away to avoid this messy `var $this = this` thing.

I also thoung of:

```
   //... (same as before)
   MyObj.prototype.doSomething= function(){
       var $this = this;
       externalFunction(this.someVar, this.internalFunc, this);
   };
   //... (same as before)
```

with

```
   function externalFunction(arg1, cbfunc, thisref){
       //bla bla things
       cbfunc.call(thisref, blablaData);
   };
```

but I also find it messy.

I think there is a better way of doing it and I'm not seeing it! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Preserving the `this` reference by assigning it to a local scoped variable is just fine

Comment: You've identified the two choices you have. There are no other options.

Comment: Yea, using a local variable for `this` (often referred to as variable name `that` in JS) is common.  Additinally, you have wrapper libraries such as underscore that uses a bind method.  See http://underscorejs.org/#bind

Comment: @ic3b3rg: that's not correct. See my answer below.

Comment: @Dancrumb right you are... good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning `this` to a local variable is fine and common.

Many libraries make your second approach easier by providing a method that returns a wrapper function and sets the execution context, e.g. [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) in jQuery (or [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) in underscore.js).

Comment: ty, now i can do it without feeling im doing it wrong, maybe later ill just see the code for the functions you told me and try to make my own imp!

Answer (score 2):

There is one other option available to you, if you're on a recent enough browser and that is to use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

This allows you to create a function that has been bound to a specific scope. Put another way, it allows you to define what `this` will be, inside that function. Thus, you could do it this way.

```
MyObj.prototype.doSomething= function(){
   externalFunction(this.someVar, this.internalFunc.bind(this, data));
};
```

Follow the link above and scroll to the bottom to see information about browser support.

### Edit

Actually, there's one other option, which is to use one of the many libraries and frameworks that are out there. Any one worth its salt will have a `bind`, `hitch`, `proxy` or otherwise available to you. However, all these are doing are wrapping up the native JS approaches, but they often provide useful additions that make this technique even more valuable.

Comment: i cannot be sure if the users have a "recent enough browser", and i neither want to depend on some external lib just for some lines of code, but thanks for giving me the name to google them!